# Group representation of Standard Model

Tags: standard-model, group-theory, representation-theory

On page 527 of [Srednicki's textbook "Quantum Field Theory"](http://web.physics.ucsb.edu/~mark/qft.html), the Standard Model is described as follows:

> It can be succinctly specified as a gauge theory with gauge group $SU(3) \times SU(2) \times U(1)$, with left-handed Weyl fields in three copies of the representation $(1, 2, -\frac{1}{2}) \oplus (1, 1, +1) \oplus (3, 2, + \frac{1}{6}) \oplus (\overline{3}, 1, -\frac{2}{3}) \oplus (\overline{3}, 1, +\frac{1}{3})$, and a complex scalar field in the representation $(1, 2, -\frac{1}{2})$. Here the last entry of each triplet gives the value of the $U(1)$ charge, known as $\it{hypercharge}$.

I am puzzled by the group representation $(1, 2, -\frac{1}{2}) \oplus (1, 1, +1) \oplus (3, 2, + \frac{1}{6}) \oplus (\overline{3}, 1, -\frac{2}{3}) \oplus (\overline{3}, 1, +\frac{1}{3})$. How does it come about? What are the steps (if any) to get this representation?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Who chooses the representation of SM particles?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/319483/)

Comment: I want to know the matchematical steps to derive this representation, which is not provided in the question and answer that you mentioned.

Comment: What do you want to derive that *from*?

Comment: I don't know from what and how to derive this representation. I just saw it in Srednicki's textbook. That's why I am puzzled. I guess it is derived from a representation of $SU(3) \times SU(2) \times U(1)$. I want to know the mathematical steps to derive it.

Comment: The specific representations that are chosen in the SM are a physical input, and can't be derived from  the group. Are you asking how to see that the numbers $(1,2, -\frac{1}{2})\oplus\cdots$ correspond to the particle content of the model?

Comment: Exactly. I want to know how the numbers $(1, 2, -\frac{1}{2}) \bigoplus ... $ correspond to the particle content of the model.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your text assumes you are familiar with the quantum number content of the elementary particle [fermions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Model_(mathematical_formulation)#Fermion_fields), determined by the Millikan oil-drop experiment, structure functions of the light quarks, V-A structure of the weak currents, etc. These are experimental inputs and they come from out there, your world.

It helps you summarize the self-evident logic of their apparently diverse quantum numbers so you could write a compact QFT for them, that's all. I assume you seek an appreciation of the manifest logic involved.

It gives you the *SU(3)* color rep, singlet for leptons, color **3** for quarks, or color anti triplet for antiquarks. Likewise, their *SU(2)* weak isospin, vanishing for right handed singlets, and doublet for left-handers. (No separate 2-bars, of course, as *SU(2)* is pseudoreal.)
And, of course, mutatis mutandis for their CPT conjugates. You only have singlets and fundamental reps, since these are fundamental fermion building blocks of our world.

Thus,

- (1,2,-1/2) , e.g. for $e _L$
- (1,1,1), e.g. for $\overline {e _R}$
- (3,2,1/6) e.g. for $u_L, d_L$
- ($\bar 3$,1,-2/3) for $\overline{u_R}$
- ($\bar 3$,1,1/3) for $\overline{d_R}$.

The hypercharge in the third entry is dross -- an error-correction number, if you wish, given by $Y_W\equiv Q-T_3$, once you input the charge, in the  "minority usage", but actually modern  mainstream [definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_hypercharge), so you might have to multiply it by 2 to agree with hidebound historical listings, like those linked here. It is the eigenvalue of U(1), as your particles are all singlets, of course, under it, and multiplies the *B* coupling charge of the fermion currents. The sooner you get used to its Golden Mnemonic, the better: It is ***the average charge of isomultiplets***.

There is nothing more to it. Given these numbers you may completely, and concisely specify the fermion sector of the SM QFT.

Comment: The right-handed electron should have an electric charge -1, but you put a + on it. Is this an error?

Comment: The right-handed electron indeed has charge and hypercharge -1. But what I have in there is the positron in the weak isospin isosinglet, which is L, conjugate to the electron R. This is the gist of Srednicki's convention: he writes down *only* left-handed fields, so for the R electron he writes down the L positron. Perhaps I should have written an overbar. Let me do that.